# Definir input radio como checked em modal usando JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Tenho um modal que recebe dados de um BD. O transporte dos dados está ok.

Um dos campos é do tipo **radio**, com o seguinte código:

```html
<div class="row">
  <label class="col-1"><strong>Status:</strong></label>
  <div class="col-11">
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
      <input name="status" id="status0" type="radio" required="required" class="custom-control-input" value="A">
      <label for="status0" class="custom-control-label">Ativo</label>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
      <input name="status" id="status1" type="radio" required="required" class="custom-control-input" value="D">
      <label for="status1" class="custom-control-label">Inativo</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Esse campo recebe do BD os valores "A" (Ativo) ou "I" (Inativo). Preciso atribuir o checked a uma das opções através de JavaScript mas não está funcionando.

O fragmento de código que faz essa tarefa é esse aqui:

```js
var status = button.data('status');
if (status == "A") {
  modal.find('#status0').checked;
}
else if (status == "I") {
  modal.find('#status1').checked;
}
else {
  alert("Valor indefinido para o campo Status");
}
```

Tentei com ***document.getElementById(status0)*** sem sucesso.

Tentei com ***document.getElementsByName("status")[status0]*** sem sucesso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver alterando o código do JavaScript para:

```js
if (status == "A") {
  $('input[id=status0]').prop('checked', true);
}
else if (status == "I") {
  $('input[id=status1]').prop('checked', true);
}
else {
  alert("Valor indefinido para o campo Status");
}
```

O status **checked** na verdade é uma propriedade.

Comment: Bastava usar, por exemplo, `$('#status0').prop('checked', true);`. O símbolo `#` significa o `id` do elemento.